# Notation in Uspensky's Theory of Equations

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-equations

On Page 62 of my copy of Uspensky's *Theory of Equations* (chapter III, section 5, "Relations between Roots and Coefficients"), I've come across some notation that I'm not familiar with--to the extent that I'm not even sure how I'd google it.

The expression looks like this:

$$\left. \begin{array}{rl} 
P(x + b_{n+1}) = x^{n+1} &+ s_1 \\ \quad & + b_{n+1} 
\end{array} \right | 
\left. \begin{array}{rl}
x^n & + s_2 \\ &+ b_{n+1}s_1
\end{array} \right | 
\left. \begin{array}{rl}
x^{n+1} + . . . &+ s_i \\ & +b_{n+1}s_{i-1}
\end{array} \right |
\begin{array}{l}
x^{n+1-i} + . . . + s_{n}b_{n+1} \\ \quad
\end{array}$$

The polynomial in question is $P(x) = (x + b_1)(x + b_2) . . . (x + b_n)$

$s_1$ is the sum of $b_1, b_2, . . . b_n$

$s_2$ is the sum of the products taken two at a time (e.g. $b_{1}b_2$, $b_{1}b_3$, etc.)

$s_3$ is the sum of the products taken three at a time

...

$s_i$ is the sum of the products taken $i$ at a time

...

$s_n$ is the product of all $b_n$.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context, as in where this appears? We don't all have a copy of the book.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I realized after I posted this that it needed a fair bit of additional context. I've been staring at it long enough that I forgot that the $s_i$s and $b_i$s needed to be defined. Hopefully the added bits make the expression clearer. This arises in the context of a discussion of the relationship between roots and coefficients.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it - the author is just organizing similar coefficients in columns.

Comment: @SeanRoberson So you're saying I should read this as $x^{n+1} + s_{1}b_{n+1}x^n + s_{2}b_{n+1}s_{1}x^{n-1} ... $ ?